# Why wouldn't FlushConsoleInputBuffer work as expected?

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to read console input in a loop, using Win32 API. I'm using the following (simplified) code:

```
do {

    WriteConsoleW(hStdout, L"Enter text: ", wcslen(L"Enter text: "), NULL, NULL);

    if (!ReadConsoleW(hStdin, buf, 1, &nCharsRead, NULL)) {
        // ... Handle error...
    }

    if (!FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hStdin)) {
        // ... Handle error ...
    }

    // ... Handle input ...

} while (!bValid);
```

However, for any length of input, unless I'm quitting the loop - ReadConsoleW will keep reading one character at a time (including the line break), but even after the FlushConsoleInputBuffer call the rest of the input will not be discarded. For example, if I'll enter a single letter - I'll see "Enter text: " printed three times. For 2 letters input it would be 4 prints, and so on.
According to the FlushConsoleInputBuffer [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the console input buffer should be cleaned:

> Flushes the console input buffer. All input records currently in the input buffer are discarded

Is there a bug in this function, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If the console is in line mode then `ReadConsole` doesn't return until it sees that the `ENTER` key has been pressed.  To provide this functionality, I guess it consumes low-level console input events and translates them into characters until it sees an `ENTER`.  By the time you call `FlushConsoleInputBuffer`, all the low-level events have already been consumed by `ReadConsole` so there is nothing to clear.

Comment: Use ReadConsoleInput() instead.

Comment: @arx is correct: `ReadConsoleW` is a high-level console input function. `FlushConsoleInputBuffer` and `ReadConsoleInput` are low-level functions. Mixing high-level and low-level input can be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The ReadConsoleW function adds the line break caused by the enter key as two additional characters.